# Anidar bucles for en Shell-script

Tags: bash, shell-script

me hace falta anidar bucles para mostrar por pantalla el siguiente texto sacado de un fichero llamado grupos.txt:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido del fichero grupos.txt es el siguiente::
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
clear 
read -p "Introduce el nombre del archivo: " nombre
if [ ! -f $nombre ];then
echo "incorrecto"
else
echo "En el fichero proporcionado tenemos 4 grupos:"
for i in $(cat grupos.txt | awk '{print NF}')
do
for cabecera in $(cat grupos.txt | awk '{print 1}' | head -$i | tail -1)
do
echo "$cabecera $i usuarios"
done
done
fi
```

Sin embargo el resultado no es el esperado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ya que se me repite la palabra "asir:" en las 4 líneas en vez de mostrarme cada una de las líneas, es decir: para la primera línea debería de mostrarse "administradores:", en la segunda línea "dam:", tercera línea "daw:" y cuarta línea "asir:" tal cual está en la imagen. Si alguien me puede echar una mano con el código se lo agradecería, gracias.

Comment: el problema reside en que estás haciendo `cat grupos.txt | awk '{print 1}'`, que siempre imprime un "1", literalmente. Supongo que querrías decir `$1`. En cualquier caso, el código es muy poco óptimo y un simple `awk '{printf "%s %d usuarios\n", $1, NF-1}' grupos.txt` sería más que suficiente para hacer todo lo que le pides

Comment: Correcto, el código es demasiado pobre puesto que estoy empezando en el mundillo de la programación, en cualquier caso, te agradezco muchísimo la aportación!